# Magento 2 custom product attribute won't save

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, magento2, entity-attribute-value

I am writing a magento 2 module - am trying to get it to add a custom attribute to every product. My "Setup>InstallData.php" file is successfully adding the attribute to the "eav_attribute" table when installing the module, and the adminhtml is rendering the field as having "name=product[my_attribute]", which I think means that it "accepts" the field as being a valid part of the model. However, when attempting to save the product with a value in the custom attribute, nothing is saved in the database.

here is my code:

```
<?php

// module namespace is 'Duel', module name is 'Gallery'
namespace Duel\Gallery\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */

    $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    /**
    * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
    */

    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'my_attribute', 
        [
            'type' => 'text',
            'backend' => '',
            'label' => 'My New Attribute',
            'input' => 'text',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true
        ]
    );
}
}
```

and here is the html in view>adminhtml>ui_component>product_form.xml

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="attributes">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">MY CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
        </item>
    </argument>  
    <field name="my_attribute">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My new attribute</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

I briefly had it saving after manually changing a couple of fields of 'my_attribute' in the 'eav_attribute' table, however I committed the code but stupidly didn't save the exact mysql database state and now can't get it to work again (upon testing that it creates a working form every time the module is installed).

Massive thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you should change the key in the array from user_defined to **is_**user_defined and everyhing will be right. It could save it....

Comment: Both are valid. `is_user_defined` is mapped internally to `user_defined`.

Answer (score 0):

user_defined = true ( Only create attribute e don't assign for any attribute set )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).